# Как поставить пробел перед первым русским символом?

Tags: python

У меня есть строка. Мне нужно перед первым русским символом поставить пробел, а первый пробел заменить на нижнее подчёркивание.
Вот что я имею:

```
s = 'come backвозвращаться'
```

Вот что мне нужно:

```
s = 'come_back возвращаться'
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может, не самый оптимальный вариант.

```
import re
s = s.replace(' ', '_', count=1)
ind = s.index(re.findall('[А-яё]',s)[0])
s = '{} {}'.format(s[:ind], s[ind:])
```

Comment: ЕМНИП, `ё` не входит в `а-я`.

Comment: @andy.37, действительно. Тогда, так `re.findall('[А-яё]', 's')`

Comment: `s.replace()` заменит все пробелы на подчеркивания (если их больше одного в исходной строке). Нужно добавить третий параметр: `s = s.replace(' ', '_', count=1)`

Answer (score 1):

В данный момент я не могу протестить свой пример, но должно быть что-то типа такого:

```
result = []
old = ' '
for ch in s:
    if ord != 32 and ord(ch) > 122 and 96 < ord(old) < 123:
        result.append(" " + ch)
    elif ord == 32:
        result.append("_")
    else:
        result.append(ch)
    old = ch

print ''.join(result)
```

Таблица [ASCII](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/american-standard-code-information-interchange/ascii-codes-table.png)

Есть одно но в данной реализации: пробел будет добавляться перед любым символом не являющимся латиницей или пробелом. Для более корректной работы, Вам нужно посмотреть `ord` от кириллицы, она скорее всего будет разной для разных кодировок, и соответственно поменять первое условие под эти значения.

Возможно кто-то подскажет решение через регулярные выражения.